# How can I scrape a directory of a website that doesn't have it's own webpage?

Tags: pdf, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the PDFs from https://evemaps.dotlan.net/pdf/, but going to the link simply returns a 404 error (there is no webpage for that directory). It is definitely a directory that exists, because going to https://evemaps.dotlan.net/pdf/Aridia.pdf, for example, works just fine.

How can I scrape those PDFs off and download them? There are literally 66 of them, I don't want to have to go through them all manually lol.

Let me know if there's more information I should provide!

Comment: @KJ there are definitely at least 66... there are 66 that I am specifically looking for, that I know are there :shrug: I can't get curl to work on my slightly old laptop, is there a better option?

Comment: @KJ Windows 11.

Comment: @KJ It can't find anything :sob: it says it received nothing

Comment: But yes curl did work. It just said "remote file name has no length"

Comment: Ah right, curl for all of them separately. I really need to do that. I was trying to do it for the directory itself... which it seems is impossible, no matter what tool I use. thanks for the help! (you should make this an Answer, so that I can give it a checkmark :) )

Comment: hahaha, makes sense. That last one above (DOTLAN-EVE-Regions) doesn't work anyway, the site author removed it and forgot to remove the link to it lol